# How to use custom validation attributes on an array of inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I'm using Laravel to build a form that contains an array of inputs and I’m having difficulty in showing the translated attribute name when a validation error occurs. For simplicity sake I will post a simple example of my problem.

Form inside the view:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('photo.store') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('testfield') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label class="control-label"
                   for="testfield">{{ trans('validation.attributes.testfield') }}</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="testfield" type="text" id="testfield"
                   value="{{ old('testfield') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('testfield'))
                <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('testfield') }}</p>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('testfieldarray.0') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label class="control-label"
                   for="testfieldarray-0">{{ trans('validation.attributes.testfieldarray') }}</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="testfieldarray[]" type="text" id="testfieldarray-0"
                   value="{{ old('testfieldarray.0') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('testfieldarray.0'))
                <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('testfieldarray.0') }}</p>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('testfieldarray.1') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label class="control-label"
                   for="testfieldarray-1">{{ trans('validation.attributes.testfieldarray') }}</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="testfieldarray[]" type="text" id="testfieldarray-1"
                   value="{{ old('testfieldarray.1') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('testfieldarray.1'))
                <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('testfieldarray.1') }}</p>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Gravar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Rules function in the form request:

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = [
        'testfield' => array('required'),
    ];

    foreach ($this->request->get('testfieldarray') as $key => $val) {
        $rules['testfieldarray.' . $key] = array('required');
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

lang/en/validation.php

```
'attributes' => [
    'testfield' => 'Test Field',
    'testfieldarray' => 'Test Field Array',
],
```

The validation is performed correctly, as do the error messages. The only problem in the error messages is the name of the attribute displayed. In both array inputs, the attribute name inserted in the message is 'testfieldarray.0' and 'testfieldarray.1' instead of 'Test Field Array'. I already tried to add on the language file 'testfieldarray.0' => 'Test Field Array', 'testfieldarray.1' => 'Test Field Array', but the messages remain unchanged. Is there a way to pass the attribute names correctly?

Comment: You could loop though every 'testfieldarray' for the custom messages array in the validation, just as you do with the rules. After googling for 1sec http://ericlbarnes.com/laravel-array-validation/

Comment: Shouldn't you add `attributes.` before `'testfieldarray.' . $key`

Answer (score 1):

**Just see the example to add custom rules for integer type value check of array**

Open the file

```
/resources/lang/en/validation.php
```

Then add the custom message.

```
// add it before "accepted" message.
'numericarray'         => 'The :attribute must be numeric array value.',
```

Again Open another  file to add custom validation rules.

```
/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
```

So, add the custom validation code in the boot function.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['validator']->extend('numericarray', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        foreach ($value as $v) {
            if (!is_int($v)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Now you can use the **numericarray** for integer type value check of array.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'input_filed_1' => 'required',
            'input_filed_2' => 'numericarray'
        ]);
```

----------- **Best of Luck** --------------

Answer (score 1):

1-if you split  the **validation** in  file **request** then add the method **attributes** and set the value of each key like this :

```
 public function attributes()
    {
        return [
          'name'=>'title',
         

        ];
    }
```

2- but if don't split the validation of the request then you just need to make variable **attributes** and pass the value of items like this :

```
$rules = [
  'account_number' => ['required','digits:10','max:10','unique:bank_details']
];
$messages = [];
$attributes = [
    'account_number' => 'Mobile number',
];
$request->validate($rules,$messages,$attributes);
// OR
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [custom error messages](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages) inside your parent method....

```
public function <metod>(Request $request) {
    $rules = [
        'testfield' => 'required'
    ];
    $messages = [];

    foreach ($request->input('testfieldarray') as $key => $val) {
        $rules['testfieldarray.' . $key] = 'required';
        $messages['testfieldarray.' . $key . '.required'] = 'Test field '.$key.' is required';
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules,$messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $request->flash();
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
}
```